# Should a start-stop interrupt positive or negative? (Why?)

Tags: switches, relay, polarity

[This answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/586146/232742) shows a "standard" start-stop circuit.

I was trying to design my own, and came up with a design that is essentially the same, except that it interrupts negative, with positive always directly connected to the load.

As far as I know, this makes no difference, but I know just enough about electricity to be dangerous, and I couldn't find anything already addressing this question. In a DC circuit, does it matter whether a switch interrupts the positive or negative side of the circuit? In other words, of the two circuits shown below, is there any reason to prefer one over the other?

(For bonus points, did I get the design of these "sort-of-latching" switches correct? Exactly as in the cited answer's question, the goal is for the circuit to turn on when the momentary switch is closed and remain on until power is lost.)

[image: circuits]

Comment: Why does your load route through your button? As drawn there would be no difference. The differences come in when you introduce other things and how they might connect to your load ( and if AC it would affect safety since earth is associated with one of the supply terminals and you need to choose which terminal you want to be connected to the load at all times).

Comment: Where is the "stop" part of your circuit? As drawn, once you press the button to turn it on it'll never turn off.

Comment: @DKNguyen, I think that's "accidental". The momentary switch has to close the circuit with the coil. The relay switch has to close the circuit with both the load and the coil. Since both connect to the coil, you end up with a path through the momentary switch to the load. I guess I could "break" that by using a DP relay, but since everything runs on 12VDC (via a mains AC to DC convertor), I'm not sure there's any point? (In particular, the load also uses 12VDC and will be powered off the same AC/DC convertor as the relay.) Maybe that's worth its own question?

Comment: @brhans, yes, that's the idea: "the goal is for the circuit to [...] remain on until power is lost". The load is meant to be always-on, but cold startup (e.g. after a mains outage) needs to be supervised. Interruption of the power supply would turn it off, and should reset it to "off". (That's "should" both in the sense of what I believe will happen, and what is *intended* to happen.)

Comment: @DKNguyen, in fact, if you compare my lower circuit to the one in the linked question, AFAICT they're identical (aside from the load being shown as a lamp, rather than "generic"). To wit, that one also has a loop from BAT to SW to LAMP to BAT.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141275/discussion-between-matthew-and-andy-aka).

Comment: You usually switch the side that is not ground, because there's _much_ more ground than not-ground to accidentally come in contact with.

Comment: @mow, um... okay. That makes sense when dealing with AC, when you have a neutral that is nominally zero voltage. What about when dealing with a purely DC circuit that otherwise has equal "stuff" on the positive and negative sides; is there a "preferred" side to interrupt in *that* case? (I feel like there might be a full Answer hiding somewhere in there...)

Comment: If this was part of a larger system, then the difference could have implications. By convention, normally the positive side would be switched as this leaves the 0V intact which is usually the reference for everything else. Switching 0V can cause ‘sneak circuits’ in larger systems. A sneak circuit is an unintentional electrical  path that occurs in some circumstances. For your simple light circuit, this isn’t the case. For convention’s sake, switch the positive.

Comment: Hi/lo side logic questions are irrelevant and common knowledge. A low side LED driver replaces an inverter.  The same applies to latches.  e,g, TTL was active low S/R while CMOS is active high and relay coils and LEDs may be inverted by polarity of the switch location.  Can you expand on your design details or do you not have any design specs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design is totally fine. Switching to the high or low side is mostly a matter of industry specific tradition, and not so much an important technical issue. Remember that there is no real reason for why we defined some voltages as positive, and some others as negative. Physicists in the 19th century simply chose at random, and we stuck with their convention. The only thing that matters for the potential work that can be performed is the absolute voltage difference between 2 points.

There are (of course) some exceptions. 230/110 Vac applications in domestics settings are almost always switched on the 'high' or hot side, because the 'low' neutral wire is connected to the earth. This means that there is no voltage between a device and your body if the switch is disconnected. The same logic is used in cars, where the frame is connected to the negative terminal of the battery.

In most settings discussed on this board, however, both power supply rails will be floating relative to the earth. In this situation, both high and low side switching are equaly safe.